# changed value has not been saved into content editable div

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, contenteditable

I am trying to change/replace some text in content editable div with python using selenium-webdriver.

But it has not been saved after the change. 
Where can be the problem? If I don't get any kind of error.
Here are what I am doing in my code:

```
input_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.trumbowyg-editor')

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1];", input_field, 'replaced text')
```

---

During the run, I noted that 'replaced text' is writing into textfield, but unfortunately id has not been saved.

Comment: what id has not been saved?

Comment: ups, sorry, I should have written 'it has not been saved', I mean 'replaced text' has not been saved.